# On Pesach, to which side does someone with situs inversus lean?

Tags: halacha, passover, medicine, heseiba-leaning

Situs inversus  is a condition where the body’s internal organs are reversed, apparently including the esophagus and the trachea.

Therefore, on Pesach, would a Jew with this condition lean on his right side instead of his left?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44765/759

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27185/759 the "choking" rule may not be left-right oriented

Comment: I'd expect that one only fulfills *haseba* in the regular left leaning way (as this seems to be the legally defined way to do it *derekh heruth*), with the question remaining whether someone with situs inversus is exempt (due to the possibility of *sakkana*)... +1 for interesting question :)