# Best sleeping position?

Tags: sleep, shulchan-aruch

I think it was in the Shulchan Aruch that I once read that the best sleeping position is laying sideways over the right side. I remember there were reasons for this but I can't recall what they were.

Does the Shulchan Aruch (or other jewish text) discusses the most proper way to sleep?

Comment: You sure right and not left

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8370

Comment: @msh210 Thanks! I believe this is just what I was looking for!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [falling asleep on the left side to aid digestion](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/falling-asleep-on-the-left-side-to-aid-digestion)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Happy Chanukah, first of all. Almost anytime I see biological advice, I give a small chuckle, as sometimes I wonder how accurate it may be in view of current medicine. I'm not a doctor, but, I read a lot of medical articles and speak to many doctors b/c I'm interested and b/c I have assorted health problems. This one, definitely relates to GERD (aka reflux). Every GI I spoke to said lay on your back with the head raised. I'm not **yet** discounting Shulchan Aruch's suggestion, but I plan on showing this to my GI to get a second opinion :-)