# Guarding payos overnight

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, sleep, hair, payot-sideburns

[Men must sleep on their side,](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1204n.htm) but, besides for [aiding digestion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/falling-asleep-on-the-left-side-to-aid-digestion), this tends to mess up [long](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35677/source-for-long-payos?rq=1) nicely [curled *payos*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66351/how-does-one-grow-long-peyos?rq=1).

How does one protect [them](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/3073/nbz?tab=profile) overnight from becoming disheveled by lying on them?

Note that this is more of a problem on *shabbos* and *yom tov*, when the possibilities of fixing the *peyos* are limited. Advice that does not involve *melacha* (actions that are prohibited on *shabbos* and *yom tov*) is therefore preferred.

Comment: VTC as off topic?

Comment: @mevaqesh Why? Questions about Jewish practice is on topic.

Comment: If a bunch of Jews want to practice basketball, and are looking for advice about how to best score against the other team, that would be off topic; in spite of relevance to Jewish practice.

Comment: @mevaqesh I am asking about a practical problem that occurs when combining two practices (as in observance, not exercise) that are exclusively based in Judaism; wearing long payos out, and sleeping on one's side. I think your parallel, to *practice* basketball, is wrong.

Comment: @msh210 Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66819/may-one-beautify-his-payos

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no requirement that says you have to keep your payoth 'looking good.' But if that is priority to you then there are two different options.

If one has naturally curly hair that allows peyoth to develop naturally when drying, then on yom tov one may simply wet his hair in the morning when he gets up.

For everything else, one should wrap his peyoth around his finger, then put all the windings to the side of his head, and pin the windings to the side of his head with a bobby pin or hair pin before going to bed. And then in the next morning simply unpin your peyoth and they should fall back down into their original curly shape.